# iOS - How can I update CoreDataModel Entities?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I want to update my Entity from my app (in Swift 3 and Xcode 8).

So I have used Core Data Model.

This is the code of my CoreDataController.swift:

```
// Updates a person
    func update(updateLuci: LuciKit){
        if let luci = getById(id: updateLuci.objectID){
            luci.descrizione = updateLuci.descrizione
            luci.pin_arduino = updateLuci.pin_arduino
        }
    }

    // Gets a person by id
    func getById(id: NSManagedObjectID) -> LuciKit? {
        return context.object(with: id) as? LuciKit
    }
```

In this mode I don't have any error but if I try to restart my application I can't see the update information.

Comment: Do you save the managed object context somewhere to make the changes persistent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i think you forgot to save the context

```
func update(updateLuci: LuciKit){
        if let luci = getById(id: updateLuci.objectID){
            luci.descrizione = updateLuci.descrizione
            luci.pin_arduino = updateLuci.pin_arduino
            context.save()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the `context` like this:

```
func update(updateLuci: LuciKit){
        if let luci = getById(id: updateLuci.objectID){
            luci.descrizione = updateLuci.descrizione
            luci.pin_arduino = updateLuci.pin_arduino

            //let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            //let context = delegate.managedObjectContext

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }
        }
    }

    // Gets a person by id
    func getById(id: NSManagedObjectID) -> LuciKit? {
        return context.object(with: id) as? LuciKit
    }
```